# Autocomplete in Google forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I need to setup a survey based on Google forms. 
In this survey I need a text field with autocomplete (based on fixed allowed strings list).

I tried to set it up but the best approximation is a combo box.  On desktop version it can find values by typing but on mobile there is no keyboard when tapping the list.

Do you know if this can be done and how? 
If not,  is there a free survey service with such a function?

Comment: Google forms surveys can't be extended with Google Apps Script, only the form editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cannot be done with google forms.

s.o. is not about recommending a service so im just answering the forms question.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a choose for a list type of question if the use must use a "fixed allowed string list".  Just include all the allowable options in the list.